# Retrieve data from list by the most recent date java

Tags: java, list, csv, collections

I'm trying to collect data from my list (or group) with the most recent date for example the last monday. So I could then add values together then insert the new values back into the list.

Currently my output is looking like this

```
ID   Date       charge    balance
1   29/07/2013    10        100
2   29/07/2013    20        200
3   29/07/2013    30        300
```

Give or take a few columns. The main purpose is to group for example the entries that are the 29th, add the charge to the balance create a new entry / field / row with the new balance and the system date.

So far I've create my list and I'm able to read in the entries from csv using a scanner but i have no idea how i can get the code to get the dates without hard coding.

```
public class Statements {

    public int tncy_num;
    //public double net_rent;
    public String end_date;
    public double bal_val;
    public double chg_val;

    public Statements(int t, String ed, double bv ,  double cv){
        tncy_num = t;
        //net_rent = nr;
        end_date = ed;
        bal_val = bv;
        chg_val= cv;
    }

    public int getTncynum(){return tncy_num;}
    //public double getNetRentnum(){return net_rent;}
    public String getEndDatenum(){return end_date;}
    public double getBalValnum(){return bal_val;}
    public double getChgValnum(){return chg_val;}
    //public double getBenfValnum(){return benf_val;}
    //public double getAdjVal(){return adj_val;}
    //public double getTotlValnum(){return totl_val;}

    public String toString(){       
        return " "+this.getTncynum()+
                " "+this.getEndDatenum()+
                " "+this.getBalValnum()+
                " "+this.getChgValnum();
    }

}
```

I have a main driver class which has the main method(used to simply run the script), a coordinator class used to get the data and set the location of the csv file and other classes which return the data of the list.

```
public class Calculations {
private Coordinator cord;
private ArrayList Data;

public Calculations(Coordinator co) {
    cord =co;
    Data = new ArrayList<Statements>(cord.getData());
    System.out.print(Data); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Implement a Collections.Sort which sort your list,
- use JodaTime Library for Date http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Here an example :

```
 Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Statements>() {
  public int compare(Statements o1, Statements o2) {
    if (o1.getEndDate() == null || o2.getEndDate() == null)
       return 0;
    return o1.getEndDate().compareTo(o2.getEndDate());
 }
});
```

Comment: One question, did you compare null just for an example, also with the return number, is that simply for the index of the list @Rollyng

Comment: Hi don't deal with the index, i compare each element. And if one of your object Statements had a null value on endDate property, it can't be sort, so we put it at the end.